# Virtual Attribute, wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to setup an virtual attribute for ebm:

```
<%= form_for Ebm.new do |f| %>
<td> <%= f.text_field :ebm_findid %></td> 
......
```

And in my ebm model:

```
class Ebm < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :extra, :number, :text

def ebm_findid(name)
  self.ebm_id = Ebm.find_by_name(name)
end
end
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
ArgumentError in Categories#index

Showing C:/Sites/ruble21.07abends/app/views/ebms/_favorite.html.erb where line #21 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #21):

18: <% end %>
19: <tr>
20: <%= form_for Ebm.new do |f| %>
21:     <td> <%= f.text_field :ebm_findid %></td>
```

What do i have to change?

Comment: Could you paste the full backtrace?

Comment: Because you are passing a parameter in method, that you didn't passed while calling that method.

Comment: ok i added to my model def ebm_findid  end, and now it is working, but when i try to save it i get the error now Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ebm_findid? Should i add ebmfindid to attr_accessor?

Comment: yes, than you will be able to access that.

Comment: In the field with the virtual attribute the user enters an ebm_name, and the method find_ebmid should transform his input to an existing ebm id!

Comment: Ok still not working, now i get the error: NoMethodError in EbmsController#create

undefined method `find_by_name'

Comment: add 'name' attribute in attr_accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `NoMethodError in EbmsController#create undefined method 'find_by_name'` error:

`find_by_name` expects `Ebm` to have attribute `name`. Make sure you have it.

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot it! But now new error occurs: NoMethodError in EbmsController#create

undefined method `ebm_id=' for #<Ebm:0x39960d8>

Comment: That means that you don't have `ebm_id` attribute accessor defined. If you have such column in the database, just add `attr_accessor :ebm_id`